# wrong singular for 'slaves'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a line `resources :slaves` in my `routes.rb`. Which is definitely plural for 'slave', but rails thinks that it's plural form of 'slafe', so I get paths like `new_slafe_path`. Is there a way to tell rails correct singular form without explicitly specifying each route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very weird that Rails results in ***slafe*** instead of ***slave***. However you can add the following in your ***config/initializers/inflections.rb*** to get the desired paths.

```
#config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'slave', 'slaves'
end
```

***Note:*** You should restart the server after these changes to use in urls.